# How to get city updates for nominatim

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm using nominatim as a forward/reverse geocoder. My search target is a city. Nominatim only provides the update mechanism for countries. My current solution is to use something like osmium to get diffs from the geofabrik country updates and then apply the diff to the old city extract. Am I doing it in a roundabout way? Are there any more straightforward ways of doing this?